# Segmentation fault of CppCMS application under FreeBSD

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, freebsd, cppcms

I tried to build webpage based on CppCMS. It compiles and works under Gentoo (GCC). But I have problems when trying to build application under FreeBSD (account on hosting provider). Default compiler is Clang.

I downloaded CppCMS package and exported few variables:

```
export CC=gcc48
export CXX=g++48
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc48
```

Then as usual:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/mrozigor/libs ..
make
```

And at this moment something is probably wrong, because it fails on all tests (`make test`) with segmentation fault. But I tried to build my application and used command:

```
PATH=$HOME/libs/bin:$PATH CPATH=$HOME/libs/include:$CPATH LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libs/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH ./build.sh
```

and it build it. But when trying to exec it (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libs/lib app`) it also fails with SEGFAULT.

What is also interesting when i tried to execute command `ldd libcppcms.so` in CppCMS build directory it fails with `ldd: libcppcms.so: Shared object "libcppcms.so" not found, required by "ldd"`, but when trying same command in lib install directory then it points to proper objects.

Is this a problem with linking some libraries? Or maybe some env variables points to some Clang dependencies etc.?

**[EDIT]**

Tried with options:
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/mrozigor/libs -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc49 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++49 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc49 ..
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc49 make
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc49

Still SEGFAULTs with given backtrace, based on dump file:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000802d3fc49 in __cxxabiv1::__dynamic_cast (src_ptr=0x80300f3c0 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x802ff35d0 <typeinfo for std::locale::facet>, dst_type=0x802ff3340 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/gcc-4.9.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/dyncast.cc:60
#2  0x0000000802d76477 in std::has_facet<std::ctype<char> > (__loc=...) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/.build/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.3/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/locale_classes.tcc:110
#3  0x0000000802d67658 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_cache_locale (this=this@entry=0x606448 <std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4+8>, __loc=...) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/.build/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.3/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.tcc:159
#4  0x0000000802d67824 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init (this=this@entry=0x606448 <std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4+8>, __sb=0x80300d7c0 <__gnu_internal::buf_cout_sync>) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/.build/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.3/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.tcc:132
#5  0x0000000802d56d51 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ostream (__sb=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>, __vtt_parm=<optimized out>) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/.build/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.3/libstdc++-v3/include/ostream:85
#6  std::ios_base::Init::Init (this=<optimized out>) at /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc/work/gcc-4.9.4/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/ios_init.cc:91
#7  0x000000080112c941 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at /usr/local/lib/gcc49/include/c++/iostream:74
#8  0x000000080112c98c in _GLOBAL__sub_I_posix_time.cpp(void) () at /home/mrozigor/src/cppcms/booster/lib/ptime/src/posix_time.cpp:101
#9  0x000000080060ab77 in ?? () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#10 0x000000080060a0ee in ?? () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#11 0x0000000800608439 in ?? () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Try running your binaries in gdb might give you some clues. Which freeBSD version are you on. Maybe you are using the wrong C++ library. Try playing with setting the c++ library to the one installed by your gcc.

Comment: I tried but it looks like it fail on built libcppcms. And I can't read any useful info from gdb.

Comment: I edited question.

Comment: And it looks like GCC links library with libc++ (ldd points to libc++), but I don't know why. Should it link with libstdc++, especially if i put "-std=c++11" param?